# how to json data to be inserted in accordion in react js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

```
{
   "message": "",
   "data": [{
           "root": "Expenditure",
           "root_seq": 4,
           "group_id": 4000,
           "subgroup_seq": 18,
           "group_seq": 5,
           "rootgroup_id": 4,
           "subgroup": "Workshop Expenses",
           "amount": 1086332.17,
           "group": "Admin Expenses",
           "subgroup_id": 2112
       },
       {
           "root": "Expenditure",
           "root_seq": 4,
           "group_id": 4000,
           "subgroup_seq": 1,
           "group_seq": 5,
           "rootgroup_id": 4,
           "subgroup": "Administrative Expenses",
           "amount": 818896.55,
           "group": "Admin Expenses",
           "subgroup_id": 2113
       },
       {
           "root": "Expenditure",
           "root_seq": 4,
           "group_id": 3997,
           "subgroup_seq": 2,
           "group_seq": 4,
           "rootgroup_id": 4,
           "subgroup": "Employee Benifits",
           "amount": 12535362.01,
           "group": "Staff costs",
           "subgroup_id": 2114
       },
       {
           "root": "Expenditure",
           "root_seq": 4,
           "group_id": 4000,
           "subgroup_seq": 3,
           "group_seq": 5,
           "rootgroup_id": 4,
           "subgroup": "Communication Expenses",
           "amount": 178568.81,
           "group": "Admin Expenses",
           "subgroup_id": 2116
       },
       {
           "root": "Expenditure",
           "root_seq": 4,
           "group_id": 4000,
           "subgroup_seq": 4,
           "group_seq": 5,
           "rootgroup_id": 4,
           "subgroup": "Freight & Cartage",
           "amount": 82206.01,
           "group": "Admin Expenses",
           "subgroup_id": 2117
       },
       {
           "root": "Expenditure",
           "root_seq": 4,
           "group_id": 3997,
           "subgroup_seq": 6,
           "group_seq": 4,
           "rootgroup_id": 4,
           "subgroup": "Staff Welfare",
           "amount": 439714.02,
           "group": "Staff costs",
           "subgroup_id": 2118
       },
       {
           "root": "Expenditure",
           "root_seq": 4,
           "group_id": 4065,
           "subgroup_seq": 8,
           "group_seq": 16,
           "rootgroup_id": 4,
           "subgroup": "Interest Paid",
           "amount": 5019919.0,
           "group": "Finance Cost",
           "subgroup_id": 2120
       },
       {
           "root": "Expenditure",
           "root_seq": 4,
           "group_id": 4067,
           "subgroup_seq": 1,
           "group_seq": 1,
           "rootgroup_id": 4,
           "subgroup": "Purchase of Cars",
           "amount": 395535346.61,
           "group": "PURCHASE ACCOUNTS",
           "subgroup_id": 2121
       },
       {
           "root": "Expenditure",
           "root_seq": 4,
           "group_id": 4067,
           "subgroup_seq": 2,
           "group_seq": 1,
           "rootgroup_id": 4,
           "subgroup": "Purchase of Spares",
           "amount": 38558778.38,
           "group": "PURCHASE ACCOUNTS",
           "subgroup_id": 2122
       },
       {
           "root": "Income",
           "root_seq": 3,
           "group_id": 4083,
           "subgroup_seq": 2,
           "group_seq": 2,
           "rootgroup_id": 3,
           "subgroup": "Insurance Commission",
           "amount": -579371.89,
           "group": "Sale of Services",
           "subgroup_id": 2125
       },
       {
           "root": "Income",
           "root_seq": 3,
           "group_id": 4070,
           "subgroup_seq": 4,
           "group_seq": 1,
           "rootgroup_id": 3,
           "subgroup": "Parts Sale",
           "amount": -37622615.91,
           "group": "Sales Accounts",
           "subgroup_id": 2126
       },
       {
           "root": "Income",
           "root_seq": 3,
           "group_id": 4083,
           "subgroup_seq": 1,
           "group_seq": 2,
           "rootgroup_id": 3,
           "subgroup": "Labour Sales",
           "amount": -9740952.02,
           "group": "Sale of Services",
           "subgroup_id": 2127
       },
       {
           "root": "Income",
           "root_seq": 3,
           "group_id": 2999,
           "subgroup_seq": 2,
           "group_seq": 4,
           "rootgroup_id": 3,
           "subgroup": "Misc Sales Accounts",
           "amount": -2983666.52,
           "group": "Other Income",
           "subgroup_id": 2128
       },
       {
           "root": "Income",
           "root_seq": 3,
           "group_id": 4070,
           "subgroup_seq": 2,
           "group_seq": 1,
           "rootgroup_id": 3,
           "subgroup": "New Vehicle Sales",
           "amount": -439036264.75,
           "group": "Sales Accounts",
           "subgroup_id": 2129
       },
       {
           "root": "Income",
           "root_seq": 3,
           "group_id": 4070,
           "subgroup_seq": 7,
           "group_seq": 1,
           "rootgroup_id": 3,
           "subgroup": "Parts & Accessories",
           "amount": -1841715.3,
           "group": "Sales Accounts",
           "subgroup_id": 2156
       },
       {
           "root": "Expenditure",
           "root_seq": 4,
           "group_id": 4000,
           "subgroup_seq": 5,
           "group_seq": 5,
           "rootgroup_id": 4,
           "subgroup": "Travelling Expenses",
           "amount": 840058.39,
           "group": "Admin Expenses",
           "subgroup_id": 2164
       },
       {
           "root": "Income",
           "root_seq": 3,
           "group_id": 4083,
           "subgroup_seq": 3,
           "group_seq": 2,
           "rootgroup_id": 3,
           "subgroup": "Finance Commissions",
           "amount": -2585756.65,
           "group": "Sale of Services",
           "subgroup_id": 2179
       },
       {
           "root": "Expenditure",
           "root_seq": 4,
           "group_id": 4000,
           "subgroup_seq": 6,
           "group_seq": 5,
           "rootgroup_id": 4,
           "subgroup": "Bank Chgs",
           "amount": 84670.98,
           "group": "Admin Expenses",
           "subgroup_id": 2181
       },
       {
           "root": "Expenditure",
           "root_seq": 4,
           "group_id": 4000,
           "subgroup_seq": 7,
           "group_seq": 5,
           "rootgroup_id": 4,
           "subgroup": "Subscriptions",
           "amount": 14875.0,
           "group": "Admin Expenses",
           "subgroup_id": 2183
       },
       {
           "root": "Expenditure",
           "root_seq": 4,
           "group_id": 4000,
           "subgroup_seq": 10,
           "group_seq": 5,
           "rootgroup_id": 4,
           "subgroup": "Repairs & Maintenance",
           "amount": 19516.52,
           "group": "Admin Expenses",
           "subgroup_id": 2184
       },
       {
           "root": "Expenditure",
           "root_seq": 4,
           "group_id": 4000,
           "subgroup_seq": 11,
           "group_seq": 5,
           "rootgroup_id": 4,
           "subgroup": "Selling Expenses",
           "amount": 1877129.65,
           "group": "Admin Expenses",
           "subgroup_id": 2185
       },
       {
           "root": "Expenditure",
           "root_seq": 4,
           "group_id": 3997,
           "subgroup_seq": 7,
           "group_seq": 4,
           "rootgroup_id": 4,
           "subgroup": "PF & ESI Contribution",
           "amount": 479154.0,
           "group": "Staff costs",
           "subgroup_id": 2186
       },
       {
           "root": "Expenditure",
           "root_seq": 4,
           "group_id": 4000,
           "subgroup_seq": 13,
           "group_seq": 5,
           "rootgroup_id": 4,
           "subgroup": "Printing & Stationery",
           "amount": 341302.0,
           "group": "Admin Expenses",
           "subgroup_id": 2188
       },
       {
           "root": "Expenditure",
           "root_seq": 4,
           "group_id": 4000,
           "subgroup_seq": 14,
           "group_seq": 5,
           "rootgroup_id": 4,
           "subgroup": "Professional & Consultancy",
           "amount": 677796.0,
           "group": "Admin Expenses",
           "subgroup_id": 2189
       },
       {
           "root": "Expenditure",
           "root_seq": 4,
           "group_id": 4000,
           "subgroup_seq": 15,
           "group_seq": 5,
           "rootgroup_id": 4,
           "subgroup": "Taxes & Licenses",
           "amount": 20000.0,
           "group": "Admin Expenses",
           "subgroup_id": 2190
       },
       {
           "root": "Expenditure",
           "root_seq": 4,
           "group_id": 4000,
           "subgroup_seq": 16,
           "group_seq": 5,
           "rootgroup_id": 4,
           "subgroup": "Electricity Expenses",
           "amount": 662833.96,
           "group": "Admin Expenses",
           "subgroup_id": 2191
       },
       {
           "root": "Expenditure",
           "root_seq": 4,
           "group_id": 4000,
           "subgroup_seq": 17,
           "group_seq": 5,
           "rootgroup_id": 4,
           "subgroup": "Rents",
           "amount": 5503688.0,
           "group": "Admin Expenses",
           "subgroup_id": 2192
       },
       {
           "root": "Expenditure",
           "root_seq": 4,
           "group_id": 4000,
           "subgroup_seq": 8,
           "group_seq": 5,
           "rootgroup_id": 4,
           "subgroup": "Repairs & Maintenance - Buildings",
           "amount": 141850.0,
           "group": "Admin Expenses",
           "subgroup_id": 2193
       },
       {
           "root": "Expenditure",
           "root_seq": 4,
           "group_id": 4000,
           "subgroup_seq": 9,
           "group_seq": 5,
           "rootgroup_id": 4,
           "subgroup": "Repairs & Maintenance - P&M",
           "amount": 84813.23,
           "group": "Admin Expenses",
           "subgroup_id": 2194
       },
       {
           "root": "Expenditure",
           "root_seq": 4,
           "group_id": 4065,
           "subgroup_seq": 10,
           "group_seq": 16,
           "rootgroup_id": 4,
           "subgroup": "Interest paid to Others",
           "amount": 972877.66,
           "group": "Finance Cost",
           "subgroup_id": 2196
       },
       {
           "root": "Expenditure",
           "root_seq": 4,
           "group_id": 4065,
           "subgroup_seq": 11,
           "group_seq": 16,
           "rootgroup_id": 4,
           "subgroup": "Other Borrowing Costs",
           "amount": 327500.0,
           "group": "Finance Cost",
           "subgroup_id": 2197
       }
   ]
}
```

Hi, I just want the above JSON to be react accordion, the structure would be **root** name under that **group** under **group** name to show **subgroup** this will be handled by **group_id**. if anyone helps me it means a lot.

I want the data to be shown as in the image

[image]

Comment: Please add what you have done so far. snippet will be better :).

Answer (score 0):

you can store this json in a separate file and you can import this file where you want to use it.
Suppose your file name is example.json, then you can just import that file like

```
import response from "./example.json";
```

and you can use this response object to build accordion or anything.